# protractor: testing redirect with angular $window service

Tags: angularjs, window, protractor

In the app that I am testing, we use the [angular `$window` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) to redirect to a different URL.

For example:
when you click a button, it redirects you to a new page via:

```
$window.location.assign('/redirect/to/this/newURL');
```

In the [angular docs for `$window`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) they provide this Protractor example:

index.html:

```
<script>
 angular.module('windowExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
    $scope.doGreeting = function(greeting) {
        $window.alert(greeting);
    };
  }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="greeting" aria-label="greeting" />
  <button ng-click="doGreeting(greeting)">ALERT</button>
</div>
```

protractor.js:

```
 it('should display the greeting in the input box', function() {
    element(by.model('greeting')).sendKeys('Hello, E2E Tests');
    // If we click the button it will block the test runner
    // element(':button').click(); 
 });
```

The test states:

> If we click the button it will block the test runner.

I am wondering what this means exactly. I am curious why and how it blocks the protractor test runner? And how does that impact trying to test that feature? It looks like `ignore.Synchronization=true` may help with testing in some of these cases, but hoping I can gain a better understanding of why the $window service breaks the tests in hopes of finding good solutions for testing these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just that there will be an alert box displayed if you click the button.

In Protractor, you may then *switch to it*, check the text and close:

```
var alertDialog = browser.switchTo().alert();
expect(alertDialog.getText(), 'Hello, E2E Tests');
alertDialog.accept();  // or alertDialog.dismiss();
```